# Share PHP string to Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, string, post, share

I was wondering if it was possible to use PHP / AJAX to have a string of text sharable to Facebook? For example, I use PHP to return an SQL query, then use that same string of text in correspondence with a button, to share to my Facebook wall. So, it might look something like this in the PHP:

```
while($note_row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

echo '<p> "' . $note_row['my_note_text'] . ' "</p>';

echo '<input type="button" id="' . $note_row['my_note_id'] . '" class="share-to-facebook" value="share" />';

}
```

If anyone has some advice whether this is possible I'd be super happy. I also apologise if my PHP is wrong, I haven't checked it.

Comment: Not sure if it has anything to do with your code now working the way you wanted, but I did fix a missing `'` in your code. Just saying.

Comment: I'm going to suggests reading up on the PHP API here, specifically the section about Posts: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

I also think you'll get more out of Stackoverflow if you attempt to build the thing you're describing first. Then, come back later with newer, specifc questions. 

As a general rule, if your question ends with "Can I do this?" instead of "Why won't this work the way I expect?" it's probably not a good Stackoverflow question.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I had posted the comment some time ago, not realising there had been some activity. Thank you for your contributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options:

**sharer.php**

https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=407822831963

Create a share link. You can set title and url.

**Feed Dialog**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Creates a share dialog. More options for description and image etc. Might be a replacement for sharer.php.

If you need to post to the wall from your app, you need the get permissions by having the user accept your app to Facebook. Read more about authentication at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have the code operational now!